# Manage Dependencies of Multiple Targets with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, afnetworking, cocoapods

I just started tinkering with cocoapods to manage dependencies of my iOS Projects.
Currently I am trying to integrate unit tests using GHIOSUnit. I followed all their instructions and tried their sample tests and it all worked like charm.

[image: Project Setup 1]
[image]

However, problems start when I start using my actual project files for testing.

I am using AFNetworking for client server comms and whenever I access my sharedClient called 'CRLClient', a wrapper for AFHTTPClient, it gives me undefined symbols errors.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_AFHTTPClient", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CRLClient in CRLClient.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONRequestOperation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CRLClient.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPClient", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CRLClient in CRLClient.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The pod file for managing dependencies looks like this

```
workspace 'Storyboards.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '5.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '1.1.0'
target :UnitTests, :exclusive => true do
pod 'GHUnitIOS', '0.5.6'
end
```

The actual project target builds fine and works with AFNetworking perfectly.

P.S. I am required to add all the files to be tested to be added to the UnitTest Target as well. Then what does adding 'Target Dependency' in build phases do?

[image]
[image]

In short,

1. how to share common dependencies between different targets?
2. what does adding target dependencies really do if I still have to add each file to new target?

Comment: Having a similar issue. Looks like we need a way to NOT import the classes, but add the search paths for this to work…

Comment: i solved the issue by linking to the libPod.a file, generated by pods for the main project, in the Test Target as well... they look exactly the same. Perhaps not the right way to do it. HOWEVER, I still have to add each file to tested to Both targets .. =(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By using

```
target :UnitTests, :exclusive => true do
  pod 'GHUnitIOS', '0.5.6'
end
```

You're saying that the only library you want to be linked to the `UnitTests` target is `GHUnit` mainly saying you *don't* want `AFNetworking` to be linked as well. The problem is it looks like you're also importing your `AFHTTPClient` subclass into `UnitTests` where it can't find the AFNetworking components it's trying to link to.

To fix this you should be able to remove the exclusive call

```
target :UnitTests do
  pod 'GHUnitIOS', '0.5.6'
end
```

With this you will link `GHUnit` only to your `UnitTests` target but will link `AFNetworking` to both. "The target will by default include the dependencies defined outside of the block, unless the :exclusive => true option is given." (from [here](http://docs.cocoapods.org/podfile.html#target))

Comment: interesting .. will get back with results