# CocoaPods: new target added to project can't find CocoaPods Headers

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have a project(workspace) that is already configured using CocoaPods correctly. The I add a new target in my project, when importing headers in CocoaPods, the compiler complains that it can't find these headers, which can be imported in my first project.

What should change to solve this problem?

Comment: a more detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581386/manage-dependencies-of-multiple-targets-with-cocoapods

Comment: also you may encounter a duplicated symbol problem, refer here to solve it https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1729

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you use `pod install` to update the workspace ?

Comment: I tried update my new target manually, but I didn't expect that pod can do this, Thank you.

Comment: I added a new build configuration and was having problems with headers. `pod install` was the fix here too.